# How to highlight text that includes glossaries and citations?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, glossaries, highlighting, soul

I have the following text, which I am trying to highlight with the package `soul`. Given below is the unhighlighted MWE

**MWE (unhighlighted)**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}

\definecolor{added}{RGB}{161,217,155}
\newcommand{\added}[1]{{\sethlcolor{added}\hl{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Fox Mulder is a \gls{fbi} special agent educated
at Oxford~\cite{latexcompanion} who believes in the existence of
extraterrestrials and a government conspiracy~\cite{einstein}
to hide the truth regarding them~\cite{knuthwebsite}.

Dana Scully is an \gls{fbi} special agent, a medical doctor,
and scientist who is Mulder's partner. In contrast to his
credulity, Scully is a skeptic, basing her beliefs on scientific
explanations.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{latexcompanion} 
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. 
\textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}. 
Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

\bibitem{einstein} 
Albert Einstein. 
\textit{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. (German) 
[\textit{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies}]. 
Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891–921, 1905.

\bibitem{knuthwebsite} 
Knuth: Computers and Typesetting,
\\\texttt{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When I highlight it using:

```
\added{Fox Mulder is a \gls{fbi} special agent educated
at Oxford~\cite{latexcompanion} who believes in the existence of
extraterrestrials and a government conspiracy~\cite{einstein}
to hide the truth regarding them~\cite{knuthwebsite}.

Dana Scully is an \gls{fbi} special agent, a medical doctor,
and scientist who is Mulder's partner. In contrast to his
credulity, Scully is a skeptic, basing her beliefs on scientific
explanations.}
```

All I get is:

[image]

How can I highlight text which contains glossaries, citations and references in LaTeX?

**UPDATE**

[Nicola Talbot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425456/72911) works fine with single citations; however, it does on work with multiple citations. *How to get [Nicola Talbot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425456/72911) to work with multiple citations (MWE below)?*

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}

\definecolor{added}{RGB}{161,217,155}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\added}[1]{{\let\glsunset\@gobble\sethlcolor{added}\hl{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\added{Fox Mulder is a \mbox{\gls{fbi}} special agent educated
at Oxford~{\cite{latexcompanion}} who believes in the existence of
extraterrestrials and a government conspiracy~{\cite{einstein,knuthwebsite}}
to hide the truth regarding them~{\cite{knuthwebsite}}.}

\glsunset{fbi}

\added{Dana Scully is an {\gls{fbi}} special agent, a medical doctor,
and scientist who is Mulder's partner. In contrast to his
credulity, Scully is a skeptic, basing her beliefs on scientific
explanations.}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{latexcompanion} 
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. 
\textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}. 
Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

\bibitem{einstein} 
Albert Einstein. 
\textit{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. (German) 
[\textit{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies}]. 
Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891–921, 1905.

\bibitem{knuthwebsite} 
Knuth: Computers and Typesetting,
\\\texttt{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to group the parts that `\hl` can't deal with, but unfortunately even this fails with the first use of `\gls`. This can be demonstrated with the following which only works because the first use is comes before the `\hl` part:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}

\definecolor{added}{RGB}{161,217,155}
\newcommand{\added}[1]{{\sethlcolor{added}\hl{#1}}}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{fbi}.

\added{Fox Mulder is a {\gls{fbi}} special agent educated
at Oxford~{\cite{latexcompanion}} who believes in the existence of
extraterrestrials and a government conspiracy~{\cite{einstein}}
to hide the truth regarding them~{\cite{knuthwebsite}}.

Dana Scully is an {\gls{fbi}} special agent, a medical doctor,
and scientist who is Mulder's partner. In contrast to his
credulity, Scully is a skeptic, basing her beliefs on scientific
explanations.}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{latexcompanion} 
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. 
\textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}. 
Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

\bibitem{einstein} 
Albert Einstein. 
\textit{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. (German) 
[\textit{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies}]. 
Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891–921, 1905.

\bibitem{knuthwebsite} 
Knuth: Computers and Typesetting,
\\\texttt{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: image of highlighted text]

Unfortunately even adding `\mbox` fails:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}

\definecolor{added}{RGB}{161,217,155}
\newcommand{\added}[1]{{\sethlcolor{added}\hl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\added{Fox Mulder is a \mbox{\gls{fbi}} special agent.}

\end{document}
```

This results in the error:

```
! Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.
```

Part of the problem seems to be the unsetting of the first use flag, which can be demonstrated with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}

\definecolor{added}{RGB}{161,217,155}
\newcommand{\added}[1]{{\sethlcolor{added}\hl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\added{Fox Mulder is a \mbox{\glsunset{fbi}} FBI special agent.}

\end{document}
```

Adding `\protect` removes the error message:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}

\definecolor{added}{RGB}{161,217,155}
\newcommand{\added}[1]{{\sethlcolor{added}\hl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\added{Fox Mulder is a \mbox{\protect\glsunset{fbi}} FBI special agent.}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, although `\protect\gls` removes the error, it also removes the highlighting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}

\definecolor{added}{RGB}{161,217,155}
\newcommand{\added}[1]{{\sethlcolor{added}\hl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\added{Fox Mulder is a \protect\gls{fbi} special agent.}

\end{document}
```

[image: Fox Mulder is a Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI) special agent.]

The extension package [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra), as from version 1.30, has a way of temporarily buffering pending instances of `\glsunset`. This is switched on with `\GlsXtrStartUnsetBuffering` and switched off with `\GlsXtrStopUnsetBuffering` (which applies `\glsunset` to the saved labels):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}% glossaries-extra.sty
\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}

\definecolor{added}{RGB}{161,217,155}
\newcommand{\added}[1]{{\sethlcolor{added}\hl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\GlsXtrStartUnsetBuffering % glossaries-extra.sty v1.30+
\added{Fox Mulder is a \mbox{\gls{fbi}} special agent.}
\GlsXtrStopUnsetBuffering % glossaries-extra.sty v1.30+

\end{document}
```

[image: Fox Mulder is a Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI) special agent.]

For convenience, this can be incorporated into the definition of `\added`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}% glossaries-extra.sty
\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}

\definecolor{added}{RGB}{161,217,155}
\newcommand{\added}[1]{%
 \GlsXtrStartUnsetBuffering % glossaries-extra.sty v1.30+
 {\sethlcolor{added}\hl{#1}}%
 \GlsXtrStopUnsetBuffering % glossaries-extra.sty v1.30+
}

\begin{document}

\added{Fox Mulder is a \mbox{\gls{fbi}} special agent.}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately `\mbox` is still needed, which can cause paragraph justification problems as the content of `\mbox` can't be broken across a line. The other problem is that if `\gls{fbi}` is used multiple times within the same `\added` argument they will all be fully expanded as the first use flag can't be unset until `\GlsXtrStopUnsetBuffering`.

Another possibility with `glossaries-extra` v1.30+ is to move `\gls` outside of `\added` and use the `textformat` key to push `\added` further inside the internal workings of `\gls` to help `\hl` work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}% glossaries-extra.sty
\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}

\definecolor{added}{RGB}{161,217,155}
\newcommand{\added}[1]{{\sethlcolor{added}\hl{#1}}}

% command for use in `textformat` (glossaries-extra v1.30+):
\newrobustcmd{\gadded}[1]{%
  {%
   \def\glsxtrabbreviationfont##1{\GlsXtrExpandedFmt{\added}{##1}}%
   \def\glsxtrregularfont##1{\GlsXtrExpandedFmt{\added}{##1}}%
   #1%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\added{Fox Mulder is a }\gls[textformat=gadded]{fbi}\added{ special agent.}

\end{document}
```

[image: Fox Mulder is a Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI) special agent.]

With just the base `glossaries` package, or with earlier versions of `glossaries-extra`. the only partial solution I can think of in this case is a bit of a fudge:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}

\definecolor{added}{RGB}{161,217,155}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\added}[1]{{\let\glsunset\@gobble\sethlcolor{added}\hl{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\added{Fox Mulder is a \mbox{\gls{fbi}} special agent educated
at Oxford~{\cite{latexcompanion}} who believes in the existence of
extraterrestrials and a government conspiracy~{\cite{einstein}}
to hide the truth regarding them~{\cite{knuthwebsite}}.}

\glsunset{fbi}

\added{Dana Scully is an {\gls{fbi}} special agent, a medical doctor,
and scientist who is Mulder's partner. In contrast to his
credulity, Scully is a skeptic, basing her beliefs on scientific
explanations.}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{latexcompanion} 
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. 
\textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}. 
Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

\bibitem{einstein} 
Albert Einstein. 
\textit{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. (German) 
[\textit{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies}]. 
Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891–921, 1905.

\bibitem{knuthwebsite} 
Knuth: Computers and Typesetting,
\\\texttt{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: image of highlighted text]

For multiple citations it seems you need `\mbox`. For example, `\mbox{\cite{einstein,knuthwebsite}}`.

Comment: Not tested, but could we let the content of highlighted text to expand inside a vbox and use it after that? This was my idea when show the question

Comment: @koleygr It works with a savebox: `\newsavebox\mysbox\sbox\mysbox{\gls{fbi}}\added{Fox Mulder is a {\usebox\mysbox}...}`. I don't know how well it would work with a vbox.

Comment: thanks, Already tried but failed to use the full text in a `vbox` ... I don't know why yet... but my idea doesn't work (to make a `newcommand` that will save and use the content)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot The solution works fine, but I forgot to consider another scenario: multiple citations. With multiple citations I get a black square.

Comment: @nxkryptor It seems to work if you added `\mbox`: `\mbox{\cite{einstein,knuthwebsite}}`.

Comment: That worked fine.