# Tufte \newthought with \gls

Tags: glossaries, tufte

I want to insert a `\gls` acronym into `\newthought`.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} 
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym{ds}{DS}{Directional Sensitivity} % define acronym label/short/long
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newthought{The \gls{ds}} of hair cells

\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

This works as expected with `pdfLaTeX`. However, when rendered with `XeLaTeX`:

```
! Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `{ds}' has not been defined.
```

`\glossaries` v4.37

No error is throw with:

```
\newthought{The \glsentrytext{ds}} of hair cells

\newthought{The \glsentryshort{ds}} of hair cells

\newthought{The \glsentrylong{ds}} of hair cells

\newthought{The \glsentryname{ds}} of hair cells

\newthought{The Directional Sensitivity} \gls{ds} of hair cells
```

However, no acronym is rendered from all examples except the last one (because it is outside `\newthought`.

But,

- I need to use the `\gls` for the first time in `\newthought`, otherwise it mucks up later uses
- I want to use `\newthought` to emphasise the new topic, e.g. Directional Sensitivity, which is best defined as an acronym
- I want to use `XeLaTeX` for unicode support.

The output when using `pdfLaTeX`:

```
    *File List*
tufte-book.cls    2015/06/21 v3.5.2 Tufte-book class
tufte-common.def    2015/06/21 v3.5.2 Common code for the Tufte-LaTeX styles
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
 xifthen.sty    2015/11/05 v1.4.0 Extended ifthen features
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 ifmtarg.sty    2009/09/02 v1.2a check for an empty argument
hardwrap.sty    2011/02/12 v0.2 Hard wrap messages
ifplatform.sty    2010/10/22 v0.4 Testing for the operating system
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
catchfile.sty    2016/05/16 v1.7 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
    book.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    bk10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
titlesec.sty    2016/03/21 v2.10.2 Sectioning titles
titletoc.sty    2011/12/15 v1.6 TOC entries
hyperref.sty    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
ragged2e.sty    2009/05/21 v2.1 ragged2e Package (MS)
everysel.sty    2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
geometry.cfg
changepage.sty    2009/10/20 v1.0c check page and change page layout
paralist.sty    2017/01/22 v2.7 Extended list environments
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
letterspace.sty    2017/07/07 v2.7 Robust letterspacing (RS)
setspace.sty    2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2017/06/24 v1.0g Graphics/color driver for pdftex
dvipsnam.def    2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
  svgnam.def    2016/05/11 v2.12 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
bibentry.sty    2007/10/30 1.5 (PWD)
optparams.sty    2004/08/14 v0.9 multiple optional parameters in macros
placeins.sty    2005/04/18  v 2.2
mathpazo.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Palatino w/ Pazo Math (D.Puga, WaS) 
  helvet.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS) 
beramono.sty    2004/01/31 (WaS)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
textcomp.sty    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
fancyhdr.sty    2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footers
multicol.sty    2017/04/11 v1.8q multicolumn formatting (FMi)
glossaries.sty    2018/04/07 v4.37 (NLCT)
mfirstuc.sty    2017/11/14 v2.06 (NLCT)
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
    xfor.sty    2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
datatool-base.sty    2018/04/16 v2.30 (NLCT)
 amsmath.sty    2016/11/05 v2.16a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  substr.sty    2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
datatool-fp.sty    2018/04/16 v2.30 (NLCT)
      fp.sty    1995/04/02
defpattern.sty    1994/10/12
fp-basic.sty    1996/05/13
fp-addons.sty    1995/03/15
 fp-snap.sty    1995/04/05
  fp-exp.sty    1995/04/03
fp-trigo.sty    1995/04/14
  fp-pas.sty    1994/08/29
fp-random.sty    1995/02/23
  fp-eqn.sty    1995/04/03
  fp-upn.sty    1996/10/21
 fp-eval.sty    1995/04/03
glossaries-compatible-307.sty    2018/04/07 v4.37 (NLCT)
glossary-hypernav.sty    2018/04/07 v4.37 (NLCT)
glossary-list.sty    2018/04/07 v4.37 (NLCT)
glossary-long.sty    2018/04/07 v4.37 (NLCT)
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
glossary-super.sty    2018/04/07 v4.37 (NLCT)
supertabular.sty    2004/02/20 v4.1e the supertabular environment
glossary-tree.sty    2018/04/07 v4.37 (NLCT)
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
  t1pplj.fd    2004/09/06 font definitions for T1/pplj.
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
untitled-1.out
untitled-1.out
supp-pdf.mkii
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't seem to get the error message. Can you please show what version of `glossaries` you're using?

Comment: It works fine for me with `tufte-book` v3.5.2 and `glossaries` v4.37. Can you add `\listfiles` to the start of the file and show the complete file list that appears at the end of the transcript. (Unrelated but `\makeglossaries` is best put before `\newacronym`.)

Comment: It seems the problem is caused with switching to small caps. The same error can be reproduced with XeLaTeX and just `\textsc{\gls{ds}}`. There's a similar problem with `\documentclass{tufte-book} \begin{document} \chapter{Sample}\label{sample} \textsc{\ref{sample}} \end{document}` (but not if `tufte-book` is replaced with `book`).

Comment: Ahh, thank you for the diagnosis. Do you have suggestions for a method around this, besides simply not using `\gls` and `\newthought`together? I don't care if it doesn't link, just the text is fine.

Comment: It seems that `tufte-book` redefines `\textsc` to `\sotextsc` which seems to be using the `soul` package's letterspacing commands. This interferes with commands like `\gls` and `\ref`. So it's essentially the same problem as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425432